# Is it illegal to invite someone to chat room under one of his/posts?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that I think I must describe it more than a normal question or I think I must have conversation about it. In this case I create a chat room in chat.stackoverflow.com and invite some guys whom I though can help me in this issue. I invited them using some **temporary** comments under their last activities in SO (i.e under their answers or their question). After about 24 hours I will delete my comments. I want to know is this illegal?

Comment: It's not 'illegal' but it *is* highly frowned upon. Don't pester users, write good questions and the experts will find it. Most users do **not** want to be pestered in the manner you describe.

Comment: Hint: next time ask the question before you make 20 comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do not use comments on unrelated posts to bring attention to your questions or to a chatroom. I consider this an abuse of the commenting system, and will purge these comments when I see them (like I did for the 18 you just left). This typically will be accompanied by a warning about this behavior.

Everyone here who contributes content does so voluntarily and at their own leisure. A quick way to drive experts off this site is to annoy them by filling their inbox with requests to answer people's questions. That's one of the big reasons why Stack Overflow lacks a direct messaging facility.

If your question is a good one, usually experts will find it in time.

Comment: Did you deleted the chatroom also?!